# Help finding free Japanese Government bond data

Tags: market-data

Hey so I'm looking to use Japanese bond rates for the 3-month, 5-year, and 10 year government bonds going back 20 years or so.  Unfortunately I'm presenting this in a context where I have to use free (mostly government) data sources, so Bloomberg or CapIQ are out.  I've found stuff for the 10 year rate but I'm totally stuck on the 5 year and 3-month rate going further back than a few months any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MOF provides daily fitted JGB rates since 1974: [Historical Data (1974~)](http://www.mof.go.jp/english/jgbs/reference/interest_rate/index.htm), but the shortest tenor is 1-year.